# Last Modified Date Of any Web Page

Tags: wordpress

I need to check the last Modified Date of Contact Web Page which was developed via Wordpress CMS, Is there any way to fine out?

This trick does not run "javascript:alert("Last Modified " + document.lastModified)" because web page is developed by Wordpress.

Please let me know.

Comment: Couldn't you just go to the page click screen options on the top right of the screen, select revisions, scroll to the bottom of the screen and click on revisions it will show when the page was last modified and which user/author.

Comment: Thanks for replying but which screen are you exactly talking about?